# Problem in disabling canonical 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, slug

I need to disable canonical redirection of category slug. My url structure for a category page looks like

> www.sitename.com/categorybase/categoryslug/subcategory/

Now when i change the categoryslug in the url to any other word, say `catslug`, it still takes me to the same page. I want this url to return a 404 page.
My `.htaccess` file has the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I think that the solution is somewhere else as the same htaccess file is used on a different website and that site shows up a `404` page when i do the same stuff over 
there.

Thanks.